# Why does increase in 1 in chi squared stastics corresponding to 1 sigma?

Tags: variance, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

Let $y_i$ be a set of data points and $\hat y_i(a,b,c)$ be a set of estimation.
Suppose that the chi squared statics was minimized to a real number $A$.(For simplicity, suppose that $a,b,c$ were uncorrelated in the test statics.)

$$\chi^2(a_{min},b_{min},c_{min})=\sum_i \frac{(y_i -\hat y_i)^2}{\hat y_i}=A$$

Then, I was told that $[a_{min}-\beta ,a_{min}+\alpha]$ such that $\chi^2(a_{min}-\beta,b_{min},c_{min})=\chi^2 (a_{min}+\alpha,b_{min},c_{min})=A+1$ corresponding to the 1 sigma error of the estimated parameter $a$ at $a_{min}$.

Could you provide some explanation and proof over why this was?

Comment: Does knowing the mean of a $\chi^2$ is $\nu$ and the variance is $2\nu$ help at all?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I'm not quite sure how to derive from the above standard form to the one with the variance in the bottom. Also, then the result ought to be of 1 sigma squared, not 1 sigma.